# Rails 4: has many through association error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I know there are a lot of topics about this type of error and you can be sure that I read all of it but still can't figure out why this doesn't work. I still get this error:

> HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association

Here are my models:

```
#collection.rb
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :collection_releases
 has_many :releases, :through => :collection_releases
end

#release.rb
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :artist
 belongs_to :label

 has_many :collection_releases
 has_many :collections, :through => :collection_releases

 has_many :track_releases
 has_many :tracks, :through => :track_releases  

 validates :title, presence: true
end

#collection_release
class CollectionRelease < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :collection
 belongs_to :release
end
```

I don't get the error when I'm doing `collection.releases` - I only get the error when I'm trying to get all collections where the release is associated (`release.collections`)

Full Error in ruby console:

```
    2.2.1 :077 >   co.releases
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Release id: 1, created_at: "2015-09-25 14:38:59", updated_at: "2015-09-25 14:38:59", artist_id: 1, label_id: 1, title: "First Release of BF on Larj", year: nil, country: "Germany">]> 
2.2.1 :078 > trelease.collections
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :collection_releases in model Release
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:828:in `check_validity!'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:10:in `initialize'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:162:in `new'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations.rb:162:in `association'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:115:in `collections'
    from (irb):78
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/eqal/Documents/ror/matchit/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@matchit/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/eqal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.1 :079 >
```

I feel very desperate, so I'm hoping someone knows what is going wrong here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post the full error in the question?

Comment: The error message must be pointing to a particular line in your code. Can you show that line with some context?

Comment: I get this error while I was checking my model associations in through `rails console`. 

I tried `release.collections` (release is instantiate properly first). Then i get the error:  

trelease.collections
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :collection_releases in model Release

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but did you restart your console or enter `reload!` after setting up the association?

Comment: yep, i did reload and restart even though I don't think it is necessary to adapt the changes.

Comment: Do you get errors from `co.collection_releases` or `trelease.collection_releases` in the console? Are the association `id`'s correct?

Comment: `co.collection_releases` works fine, but when I try `trelease.collection_releases` I get the errror: 
`2.2.1 :081 > trelease.collection_releases
NoMethodError: undefined method collection_releases' for #<Release:0x007fe051120b40>` what does this mean now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails convention expects your through table to be named: `collections_releases`.  And your model `CollectionsRelease`.  Of course you could override if you wanted to keep the singular `collection_releases` name.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I did not know about that naming convention...